# Probability of drawing same ball until draw 4 or 'greater'?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm working on the series of two different questions.
I got the first problem without difficulty but got stuck with second problem.

Here is the first problem I'm writing for context.

You have a bag containing $2$ red balls, $4$ green balls, and $5$ purple balls. You draw one ball from the bag: it's green. Call this draw $0$. Keep this ball and continue drawing (without replacement) until you get another green ball. Call these draws $1, 2...k$. What is the probability that you don't draw another green ball until draw $3$?

I got the answer by $\large\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{8} = 0.175$, which was right.
However, next problem is somewhat tricky by its wording.

Resetting the original scenario such that draw $0$ yields a green ball, what is the probability that you don't draw another green ball until draw $4$ or greater?

I can't understand how can I get the answer for '$4$ or greater'. I just assumed it similar to first one and ended up with the answer $0.125 (\large\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{7})$ but it wasn't accurate.

What should I do for '$4$ or greater'?

Comment: Hint: Getting the first green ball at draw $4$ or later is the same as saying "none of the draws up until draw $4$ are green."

Comment: Hi platty, what's the difference between what you just said 'none of the draws up until draw 4 are green' and my last answer (7/10 * 6/9 * 5/8 * 3/7)?

Comment: never mind, I got it now! thank you for hint!

Comment: Notice that the event that you don't draw another green ball until draw $4$ or later is the complement of the event that you draw another green ball during the first three draws.

Comment: Leave out the $\frac{3}{7}$ factor in your answer.